# Setup background image size with javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the backgroud image size with javascript.

I have

```
  var test= document.createElement('div');
  test.className = 'test_element';
  test.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+image.jpg+')';
```

How do I set the background image in Javascript ONLY? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` is that your actual code?

Comment: Is `image` a variable of something? or the name of the image is `image.jpg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the background-size property

```
test.style.backgroundSize = width+'px '+length+'px';
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to use css? http://jsfiddle.net/DX5KL/1/

```
img{
    z-index:0;   
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: I need to use JS only. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try `test.style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + image + '.jpg)';`